# Getting multiple invoices from intuit anywhere api at once

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

When I update an invoice in QB (after its been changed in my system), I want to avoid updating anything that the user has modified in QB. My plan was to use the filter API method and filter by Ids to get the list of invoices from QB that my app created. However, it doesn't look like InvoiceFilter accepts ListIdSet. It does have a TransactionIdSet, but I can't find a way to get ahold of that number (i.e., the TransactionId) via Data Services. It's certainly not in the response when invoices are read. So, how do I query for a specific set of invoices via the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction id refers to the id of the invoice here.
For eg, the following invoice query will retrieve the invoice with Id 4 -

```
<InvoiceQuery xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<TransactionIdSet>
<Id idDomain="QB">4</Id>
</TransactionIdSet>
</InvoiceQuery>
```

Comment: Thanks. The docs are pretty confusing with respect to this element. It would be great to see them updated.